# How create a custom breadcrumb control in java using SWT?

Tags: java, swt, custom-controls, breadcrumbs

I have to develop a simple breadcrumb control using SWT which shows hierarchy of the system folders opened so far in a bar at the top and all the folders present at the current location in a window below. Folders should be hyper linked so one can click to move into them further. From where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the visual part, you can use the [`Breadcrumb`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/Breadcrumb) widget from the [Opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/).

It looks like this:

[image]

To handle selection, just add a `SelectionListener` to each of the `BreadcrumbItem`s.

---

Note that this is not a "hire a programmer" page, so don't expect complete solutions to your problem. If you have *specific*  questions, we are more than happy to try to answer them :)